# Text spacing in p5.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js

I'm trying to have a string of text appear hidden until hovered over, and to expand/contract dynamically when it appears. This is mostly working fine except for the characters at indices 0 and 1 which appear to share an x value.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  letters()
}

function letters() {
  let toParse = 'Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore pariatur explicabo itaque laborum. Reiciendis rem consectetur labore, molestiae pariatur laudantium eos dicta impedit tenetur vel id animi provident modi doloremque, recusandae excepturi veniam odio eaque quos delectus odit amet? Nihil vero facere maiores ducimus itaque distinctio eligendi magni, ab aliquid expedita eveniet porro, exercitationem blanditiis aliquam veritatis provident commodi a officiis illo magnam perferendis quam. Nihil alias optio mollitia aperiam consequatur, a labore ab exercitationem perferendis sunt velit ut et quisquam. Nemo ab voluptatum architecto esse iusto delectus, rem rerum velit quam ullam omnis autem sed accusamus quia! Voluptas vero qui quas natus adipisci, harum dolores fuga aperiam, officia pariatur consequatur quibusdam illo a saepe voluptatum quis temporibus cumque rerum, aliquid necessitatibus quae repudiandae excepturi? Sunt eius obcaecati eveniet laboriosam voluptate, quos impedit nam odit amet, commodi vero, accusamus aliquid accusantium fugit ducimus molestiae ex similique veniam. Fuga nam quis cupiditate ex facilis, ipsum, repellendus iure sed, consequuntur nisi illum repudiandae. Nobis ex nam, deserunt maiores facilis veritatis praesentium fugit delectus ab magni magnam laudantium, aut eum ullam aliquid cumque.'

  let parsedText = toParse.split('')

  noStroke()
  fill(223, 112, 69)
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, width / 20)

  let numLines = 4;

  for (let j = 0; j < numLines; j++) {
    let numLetters = 100
    let x = width / 10
    let y = height / 2 + height / 50 * j
    for (let i = numLetters * j; i < numLetters + numLetters * j; i++) {
      let char = parsedText[i]
      let charWidth = textWidth(char)
      let charSize = map(dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y), 0, width / 5, 24, 20)
      textSize(charSize)
      fill(map(dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y), 0, width / 4, 15, 255))
      text(char, x, y)
      // console.log(char,x,charWidth)
      x += charWidth
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.6.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Link to p5.js editor: https://editor.p5js.org/anton.ermkv/sketches/XcOQfKAuG

What is causing the overlap between the first and second characters?

[image: See how the L and the o are on top of each other?]

See how the L and o are on top of each other? And the space between e and laborum has moved to the left and effectively disappeared?

[image: Console]

Here I'm logging the character, x position, and character width (which then gets added to previous x position).

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Edited to demo in the question context. Suggestion: get it working with nothing fancy related to mouse position.

Comment: It's definitely related to the hard-coded values in `let charSize = map(dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y),...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textWidth` function takes the current `textSize` into account, but you are calculating the width of the current character *before* you update the `textSize` for the current iteration. This results in an especially egregious difference between the actual width and the calculated width for the first character in each row because the call to `textWidth` is using the `textSize` from the end of the previous row which may be very different then what ends up being rendered.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  letters()
}

function letters() {
  let toParse = 'Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore pariatur explicabo itaque laborum. Reiciendis rem consectetur labore, molestiae pariatur laudantium eos dicta impedit tenetur vel id animi provident modi doloremque, recusandae excepturi veniam odio eaque quos delectus odit amet? Nihil vero facere maiores ducimus itaque distinctio eligendi magni, ab aliquid expedita eveniet porro, exercitationem blanditiis aliquam veritatis provident commodi a officiis illo magnam perferendis quam. Nihil alias optio mollitia aperiam consequatur, a labore ab exercitationem perferendis sunt velit ut et quisquam. Nemo ab voluptatum architecto esse iusto delectus, rem rerum velit quam ullam omnis autem sed accusamus quia! Voluptas vero qui quas natus adipisci, harum dolores fuga aperiam, officia pariatur consequatur quibusdam illo a saepe voluptatum quis temporibus cumque rerum, aliquid necessitatibus quae repudiandae excepturi? Sunt eius obcaecati eveniet laboriosam voluptate, quos impedit nam odit amet, commodi vero, accusamus aliquid accusantium fugit ducimus molestiae ex similique veniam. Fuga nam quis cupiditate ex facilis, ipsum, repellendus iure sed, consequuntur nisi illum repudiandae. Nobis ex nam, deserunt maiores facilis veritatis praesentium fugit delectus ab magni magnam laudantium, aut eum ullam aliquid cumque.'

  let parsedText = toParse.split('')

  noStroke()
  fill(223, 112, 69)
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, width / 20)

  let numLines = 4;

  for (let j = 0; j < numLines; j++) {
    let numLetters = 100
    let x = width / 10
    // use a fixed height for vertical spacing
    let y = height / 2 + 24 * j
    for (let i = numLetters * j; i < numLetters + numLetters * j; i++) {
      let char = parsedText[i]
      let charSize = map(dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y), 0, width / 5, 24, 20)
      textSize(charSize)
      // calculate charWidth **after** updating textSize
      let charWidth = textWidth(char)
      fill(map(dist(mouseX, mouseY, x, y), 0, width / 4, 15, 255))
      text(char, x, y)
      // console.log(char,x,charWidth)
      x += charWidth
    }
  }
}
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.6.0/lib/p5.js"></script>
```